# GPIO Input not working if using .NET native toolchain on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot, .net-native, windows-iot-core-10

I'm currently developing an application in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) directed to an `Raspberry Pi 3`. If compiling with the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) native toolchain in the project-properties is activated, the ValueChange-Event of an input-pin does not fire. If deselecting the property, everything is working fine.

I'm not sure if it has something to do with [the problem described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806462/behavior-sdk-changepropertyaction-generates-argument-exception-in-runtime-when), but I have no idea which `type-name` could be associated with my problem.

Comment: What's your Windows 10 IoT Core version?

Comment: My current version is v.10.0.17035.1000

Comment: I test on Raspberry Pi 3 with version 10.0.17035.1000 compiling with .NET Native toolchain but can't reproduce your issue. If you can share a demo I can have a check.